# Supremum calcualtion, how do I get the answer

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Find the supremum of
`G={x|(x^2+1)^−1>1/2}` Could someone help me out with this calculation? Thanks. Appreciate.
Options are:

```
3
-1
1
2
```

[image: This is exactly the formatting of the question]

Comment: Sorry, this is meant to read $(x^2+1)-1>12$?  But then, $x$ can be infinitely large.

Comment: Thanks. How did you typed the subscript. That's where I have the formatting problem.

Comment: So it's meant to read $\frac 1{x^2+1}>\frac 12$?

Comment: Assuming you meant "superscript", the expression needs to be surrounded by \$'s.  Thus \$x^{-1}\$ compiles to $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Why is this under linear algebra tag?
Anyway, you should just solve the above inequality, shouldn't be too hard..

Comment: A useful tutorial on formatting can be found here:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Plug in all the values, and try to deduce which cannot be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(x^2+1)^{-1}&>1/2 \\
\iff x^2+1&<2 \\
\iff x^2 <1
\end{align*}